# Legendre polynomial formula

Tags: legendre-polynomials

Using the formula below to obtain Legendre polynomial $P_2(x),P_3(x) $.

$$P_n(x) =
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{ if } n = 0; \\
              & \\
x, & \text{ if } n = 1; \\
              & \\
\dfrac{1}{n}[(2n-1)xP_{n-1}(x)+(n-1)P_{n-2}(x)], & \text{ if } n \geq 2.
\end{cases}$$

My attempt:

$$P_2(x) = \dfrac{1}{2}\left(3xP_1(x) + P_0(x)\right) = \dfrac{1}{2}\left(3x\times x + 1\right) = \dfrac{1}{2}\left(3x^2 + 1 \right)$$

$$P_3(x) = \dfrac{1}{3}\left(5xP_2(x) + 2P_1(x)\right)= \dfrac{1}{2}\left(5x^3 + 3x \right)$$

But the actual result should be $P_2(x) = \dfrac{1}{2}(3x^2-1)$ and $P_3(x) = \dfrac{1}{2}(5x^3 - 3x )$.

What have I done incorrectly to the sign?

Comment: You need $\color{red}{-}(n-1)P_{n-2}$ insted of  $\color{red}{+}(n-1)P_{n-2}$ in the case $n \ge 2$.

Comment: why is that so?

Comment: This is the classical recurrence relationship. Check it on different sources.